# How to create a dynamic query?

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

I have a string like this:

```
$str = "It is a test. 10".
```

Also I have two query:

**One**: The above string is not containing any "number": (Imagine this: `$str = It is a test.`)

So, here is the query:

```
select * from table where match(col1,col2,co3) against('$str')
```

**Two:** The above string is containing some "number":

First of all I separate that number from string like this:

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
```

an then here is the query:

```
select * from table where match(col1) against('$str') and col4 IN (" .implode(',', $matches[0]) . ")";
  union all
select * from table where match(col1,col2,co3) against('$str')
```

Always one of those queries will be run (according to the condition). Now, I want to know, How can implement a dynamic query?

Comment: Do you have any errors in those queries..

Comment: @AshishRanade no, queries are fine. I need to define a condition for selecting the correct query ... I think I need to something like `CASE ... THEN`

Comment: If I am not wrong you want to use those queries as per condition right ?. Then in that case you can use the mysql procedure that will help you lot and reduce the execution time too..

Comment: @AshishRanade ah, seems I need to mysql procedure ...! well, tnx